# Visual Studio Code build task give 'The terminal shell path "dotnet" is a directory'

Tags: linux, .net-core, visual-studio-code, debian

FYI, is my first time using Visual Studio Code and on Linux. But I do have a lot of background with using Visual Studio 201x on Windows.

I've installed dotnet sdk in my Linux and setup the DOTNET_ROOT and PATH to the $HOME/dotnet.
When I run dotnet command on bash is perfectly fine.
If I run the terminal in Visual Studio and type dotnet, it runs fines too.

However, when I try to trigger a build and debug, which starts the Task - Build:

```
> Executing task: dotnet build /usr/local/myPath/dotnet-docs-samples/appengine/flexible/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.csproj /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary <

The terminal shell path "dotnet" is a directory

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Running the same command in terminal from Visual Studio Code is working fine too.  Just not with build task (CTRL+SHIFT+B => Build)

What is the reason? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 9):

Open file ".vscode/tasks.json"

In each section with `"command": "dotnet",` replace `"type": "process"`, by `"type": "shell",`

Save the tasks.json, and try again the build command (CTRL+SHIFT+B)

**Update:**

To get the right type when you create a new project, go in C# extension folder:

- Windows:
  %USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.5/dist
- Linux/MacOs: ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.5/dist

Edit the file "extension.js" and replace all occurences of

`command:"dotnet",type:"process"` by `command:"dotnet",type:"shell"`.

But you will have to do that after each C# extension update.

Comment: Awesome! Far more helpful than the VS Code developers have been. Particularly since the Github issue I just checked went down the wrong rabbit hole, and said that the tasks _were_ being run in a shell. This is far more right than the usual workaround that hardcodes the execution path in `tasks.json`

Comment: Concerning the "Update" section, I will look to open a ticket on GitHub to get a permanent fix.

Comment: I have just made a pull resquet

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea what even created `tasks.json`